# iOS OpenGL ES 2.0 GLKit GLKMatrix4 Rotate after Touches Ended

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit, quaternions

I want to achieve momentum after touches ended. I am using GLKit on iOS with Objective-C and the OpenGL ES 2.0 API. I am using Quaternions to rotate an object centered about the origin of my world using Arcball Rotation. when I rotate with touches, I want to continue the rotation with diminishing speed for some time until there is no rotation left to do.

My thoughts:
1.) Get current angle from Quaternion
2.) Convert Quaternion to 4x4 Matrix
3.) Use GLKit to rotate Matrix with decreasing angles from the current quaternion
4.) At some point invalidate the timer

I've tried to rotate the matrix after touches ended with X,Y, and Z axis independently, as well as all together, but the resulting rotation is never about the axis I would expect from my Quaternion. The arcball rotation works just fine when I move the object using my finger - it is only when the finger is released that the rotation continues about some seemingly arbitrary axis. How do I get the axis to be consistent with the last state of quaternion rotation when I lifted my finger? Also, I noticed from the docs that the GetAngle function for the Quaternion should return negative values of radians when the object is rotated counter-clockwise. I always get positive values from this function even when rotating counter-clockwise.

Thank you very much for any insight you could provide!

```
// Called when touches are ended
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    // The momentum var is initialized to a value
    self.momentumVar = 0.05;

    // Now since we stopped touching, decay the rotation to simulate momentum
    self.momentumTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.025
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(decayGLKQuaternion)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

}

// Rotate about the current axis after touches ended but for a greater angle ( radians )
- (void)decayGLKQuaternion {

    //return;

    // What is the current angle for the quaternion?
    float currentQuatAngle = GLKQuaternionAngle(self.quat);

    // Decay the value each time
    self.momentumVar = currentQuatAngle * 0.0055;

    NSLog(@"QUAT Angle %f %f",GLKQuaternionAngle(self.quat),GLKMathRadiansToDegrees(GLKQuaternionAngle(self.quat)));

    GLKMatrix4 newMat = GLKMatrix4MakeWithQuaternion(self.quat);
    float rotate = self.momentumVar * 0.75;
    //newMat = GLKMatrix4RotateX(newMat, rotate);
    //newMat = GLKMatrix4RotateY(newMat, rotate);
    //newMat = GLKMatrix4RotateZ(newMat, rotate);
    newMat = GLKMatrix4Rotate(newMat, rotate, 1, 0, 0);
    newMat = GLKMatrix4Rotate(newMat, rotate, 0, 1, 0);
    newMat = GLKMatrix4Rotate(newMat, rotate, 0, 1, 1);
    self.quat = GLKQuaternionMakeWithMatrix4(newMat);


}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in iOS, but could it be that when releasing your finger there is some "jump" in your input? What happens when you save a quaternion a few states back then use that as a reference point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simpler approach.  Don't try to decay a quaternion, or a rotational velocity.  Instead, store the movement vector of the touch (in 2D view coordinates) and decay that movement vector.

I assume that `self.quat` is the current rotation quaternion, and that in `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, you call some method that updates `self.quat` based on the touch movement vector.  Let's say the method is called `rotateQuaternionWithVector:`.  So your `touchesMoved:withEvent:` probably looks something like this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    // get touch delta
    CGPoint delta = CGPointMake(location.x - iniLocation.x, -(location.y - iniLocation.y));
    iniLocation = location;

    // rotate
    [self rotateQuaternionWithVector:delta];
}
```

(That method is from [The Strange Agency's arcball code](http://thestrangeagency.com/arcball-rotation-with-glkit/), which I used to test this answer.)

I assume you also have a method that gets called 60 times per second to draw each frame of your simulation.  I assume that method is named `update`.

Give yourself some new instance variables:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    ... existing instance variables ...

    CGPoint pendingMomentumVector; // movement vector as of most recent touchesMoved:withEvent:
    NSTimeInterval priorMomentumVectorTime; // time of most recent touchesMoved:withEvent:
    CGPoint momentumVector; // momentum vector to apply at each simulation step
}
```

When the touch starts, initialize the variables:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    priorMomentumVectorTime = touch.timestamp;
    momentumVector = CGPointZero;
    pendingMomentumVector = CGPointZero;

    ... existing touchesBegan:withEvent: code ...
}
```

When the touch moves, update the variables:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint priorLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
    pendingMomentumVector = CGPointMake(location.x - priorLocation.x, -(location.y - priorLocation.y));
    priorMomentumVectorTime = touch.timestamp;

    ... existing touchesMoved:withEvent: code ...
}
```

When the touch ends, set `momentumVector`.  This requires some care, because the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` message sometimes includes additional movement, and sometimes comes almost instantly after a separate movement event.  So you need to check the timestamp:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if (touch.timestamp - priorMomentumVectorTime >= 1/60.0) {
        CGPoint priorLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
        momentumVector = CGPointMake(location.x - priorLocation.x, -(location.y - priorLocation.y));
    } else {
        momentumVector = pendingMomentumVector;
    }
}
```

Finally, modify your `update` method (which I assume gets called 60 times per second) to update `self.quat` based on `momentumVector` and to decay `momentumVector`:

```
- (void)update {
    [self applyMomentum];

    ... existing update code ...
}

- (void)applyMomentum {
    [self rotateQuaternionWithVector:momentumVector];
    momentumVector.x *= 0.9f;
    momentumVector.y *= 0.9f;
}
```

Comment: Hi there - this solution works just great for rotating with Momentum while swiping Left or Right. But when I swipe Up or Down the momentum is not apparent - so when I remove my finger from the screen any movement stops. I've tried various combinations of the momentumVector values in the code but can't seem to get the up/down momentum to work. Do you have any ideas on why this is happening? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you calculate a quaternion each time during touch - a quaternion that rotates from the original pose to a new pose. In this case, we need the time derivative of the quaternion at the end of the touch. The result will be the direction in which the object will rotate further. However, calculating the derivative is not easy. We can approximate the derivative by finite differences:

```
deriv_q = last_q * GLKQuaternionInvert(previous_q)
```

where `last_q` is the quaternion when touch has ended and `previous_q` is the quaternion "awhile ago". This may be the previous state.

If we have the overall rotation expressed as a quaternion, we can continue the rotation by multiplying the quaternion:

```
overall := overall * deriv_q
```

The order of multiplication might be reversed based on the API (I don't know iOS).

If you do this each frame, you'll get a smooth rotation in the direction of the last stroke. But it does not attenuate. What you would want to do is to calculate the root of the quaternion:

```
deriv_q := mth root (deriv_q)
```

where `m` is the amount of attenuation. However, calculating the root is not easy, either. Instead we could transform the quaternion to another representation: axis and angle:

```
axis = GLKQuaternionAxis(deriv_q)
angle = GLKQuaternionAngle(deriv_q)
```

Now we can attenuate the angle:

```
angle := angle * factor
```

and rebuild the quaternion again:

```
deriv_q := GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndVector3Axis(angle, axis)
```

Repeat this until the absolute angle falls under a certain threshold (where there is no rotation any more).

If you need to derive a matrix to display the object, you can use the [formula from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) on the `overall` quaternion.